# proper hyperlinking of asp.net cshtml. currently going to wrong controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a categories controller and a products controller. If the category is a type I reroute to the products page. I keep routing categories to get to subcategories in my controller but at a certain point there are no more subcategories and you have a type rather than a category. i was trying to copy the same logic from my layout which works fine. I've double checked all spelling errors.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Categories" asp-action="Index">Eisen Manufacturing Network</a>
```

(note I added in the istype attribute to my categories model after. I changed the bind properties and the cshtml in order to alter the model)

How do I properly link to a separate controller? because the current method I'm trying below is not working. it takes me to the categories index even though I confirmed that the HTML went to else statement through the debugger.

````
            {
                @* @("~/img/"+item.CategoryName+".jpg") *@
                <a asp-action="index" asp-route-name="@item.CategoryName">
                    <text>@item.CategoryName</text>
                </a>
            }
            else
            {
                 <a  asp-area="" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index" asp-route-type="@item.CategoryName">
                    <text>@item.CategoryName</text>
                </a>
            } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved I'm just an idiot and didn't realize that I linked the text and an image below the if statement not shown above. had to use the same logic. works fine. stupid mistakes...